# How to search in a large JSON array and find records by multiple keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby

I have a very large dataset that's organized like this:

```
users = [
    {
        username: "Bill",
        gender: "Male",
        details: {
            city: "NY"
        }
    },
    {
        username: "Mary",
        gender: "Female",
        details: {
            city: "LA"
        }
    }
]
```

I need a quick way to search for multiple records by multiple values from multiple keys.

I have dot-separated list of keys:

```
keys = ["gender", "details.city"]
```

I need to do something like this (written in pseudo code):

```
my_users = users.any? {|user|
  keys.each do |key|
    user.key == "NY"
  end
}
```

I know this is not going to work. One of the reasons it will not work is that my list of keys is dot-separated, so I could either split it to an array of keys, as in `['gender']` and `['details']['city']`, or convert the user hash to a dot-separated object with a method like:

```
def to_o
  JSON.parse to_json, object_class: OpenStruct
end
```

Comment: What needs to "be quick"? Us helping you or the code?

Comment: `users.any?` returns `true` or `false`. Is that what you want? Please edit to show the desired return value for your example. @theTinMan, or both?

Answer (score 2):

I hope this method works like you want

```
def search(users, keys, value)
  users.select do |user|
    keys.any? do |key|
      user.dig(*key.split('.').map(&:to_sym)) == value
    end
  end
end

search(users, keys, 'NY')
#=> [{ :username => "Bill", :gender => "Male", :details => { :city => "NY" } }]
```

Answer (score 2):

For linear searching, demir's solution is a good one.

For the "must be quick" angle, you may find that an O(n) scan through your users array is too slow. To alleviate this, you may want to create an index:

```
require "set"
class Index
  def initialize(dataset)
    @index = make_index(dataset)
  end

  def find(conditions = {})
    conditions.inject(Set.new) { |o, e| o | @index[e.join(".")] }.to_a
  end

  private

  def make_keys(record, prefix = [])
    record.flat_map do |key, val|
      case val
      when Hash
        make_keys val, [key]
      else
        (prefix + [key, val]).join(".")
      end
    end
  end

  def make_index(dataset)
    dataset.each_with_object({}) do |record, index|
      make_keys(record).each { |key| (index[key] ||= []) << record }
    end
  end
end

index = Index.new(users)
p index.find("gender" => "Male", "details.city" => "NY")
# => [{:username=>"Bill", :gender=>"Male", :details=>{:city=>"NY"}}]
```

This takes O(n) time and costs extra memory to create the index once, but then each search of the dataset should happen in O(1) time. If you perform a bunch of searching after setting up the dataset once, something like this might be an option.

Comment: For a big dataset this would be MUCH faster.

Comment: You could clean up the make_index method a bit by using inject.

Comment: We are not told if multiple searches are to be made for different cities. If so, this would be useful.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, good question - i am using it to search a datatable, so there will be, indeed, multiple searches. Testing the solutions here and will try to compare speeds.

Comment: We need to know what you will be searching for. Presumably it not always a city, as `users[:gender]` would not give you that. As I said you a comment on your question you need to edit your question to clarify the desired return value. Please also indicate the variety of strings you may be searching for. I really don't know what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use traverse the hash dynamically with `Hash#dig` which was introduced in Ruby 2.3.0:

```
def select_users(users, conditions)
  users.select do |user|
    conditions.select do |key, value|
      user.dig(*key.to_s.split(".").map(&:to_sym)) == value
    end.length == conditions.length
  end
end
```

This assumes that the input for conditions is a hash such as:

```
{ "gender" => "Male", "details.city" => "NY" }
```

And is optimized for testing multiple conditions in a single linear pass. You could also support arrays to test for inclusion:

```
def select_users(users, conditions)
  users.select do |user|
    conditions.select do |key, value|
      actual = user.dig(*key.to_s.split(".").map(&:to_sym))
      if value.is_a?(Array)
        value.includes?(actual)
      else
        actual == value
      end
    end.length == conditions.length
  end
end
```

```
# get users where city is "NY", "Detroit" or "Los Angeles"
select_users(dataset, { "gender" => "Male", "details.city" => ["NY", "Detroit", "Los Angeles"] })
```

Comment: `hsh.dig(*key)` is very nice :)

Answer (score 0):

The code in the question (`any?`, in particular) suggests that the object is to determine if, for any hash `h` in `users`,

```
h[:gender] == city #=> true
```

or there exists a hash `g` for which:

```
g = h[:details]
g[:city] == city   #=> true
```

**Code**

```
def city_present?(users, *key_groups, city)
  key_arr = key_groups.map { |s| s.split('.').map(&:to_sym) }
  users.any? { |h| key_arr.any? { |keys| h.dig(*keys) == city } }
end
```

**Examples**

For `users` given in the question and

```
city_present?(users, "gender", "details.city", 'NY') #=> true
city_present?(users, "gender", "details.city", 'LA') #=> true
city_present?(users, "gender", "details.city", 'TO') #=> false
```

**Explanation**

See [Hash#dig](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Hash.html#method-i-dig). `key_arr` is found to equal:

```
[[:gender], [:details, :city]]
```

**Repeated searches**

Taking up @ChrisHeald's suggestion, if `users` were large and repeated searchers were to be made for different values it would make sense to create a set of the values associated with `key_groups`. That could be done as follows.

```
require 'set'

def values_present(users, *key_groups)
  key_arr = key_groups.map { |s| s.split('.').map(&:to_sym) }
  users.each_with_object(Set.new) do |h,set|
    key_arr.each do |keys|
      v = h.dig(*keys)
      set << v unless v.nil?
    end
  end
end
```

```
values_present(users, "gender", "details.city")     
  #=> #<Set: {"Male", "NY", "Female", "LA"}>
```